# A simple WPF MVVM pattern implementing opening the child form based on selected combo box from parent form

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am new to WPF and MVVM. Can help me with the below case. Thanks in advance :)
Based on Condition 1, Form1 opens. If Condition 1 is not satisfied then Form 2 is opened. And User selects the combo box from form 2, based on combo box selectedvalue,  Form 1 should get opened. It follows WPF + MVVM architecture

Comment: I didn't downvote You but i guess I should. It's not write code for me website. Show us what you've already tried

Comment: `Form1` or `Window1`? You made me miss the old technology Winforms.

Comment: I did downvote. We're not here to do your job. At least show something you've tried instead of copy/pasting your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

This is your lucky day. Just happened came across a page with exactly what you need. It's actually the 2nd suggestion by googling "beginner wpf mvvm tutorial".

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/126249/MVVM-Pattern-in-WPF-A-Simple-Tutorial-for-Absolute

Comment: it should be even luckier for her if you extract some essential code from that link into your answer. Although it's from codeproject but there is always a chance it may be removed in future.

Comment: Copy and paste or reverse engine from an existing project could be a some-what good experience for beginner programmer. I remember the computer science 101 textbox also require the student to copy a main method and then ask the student to make enhancement on it ? hahah